# Executing code when leaving page

Tags: flutter

I would like to execute some code whenever a page in my app is left.
I would prefer to use a general solution rather than managing the cases where the user can go back. I've tried to use the `dispose()` and `deactivate()` calls but they don't work as expected (I've added some debug messages but they don't appear when I leave the page).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) is a widget that can execute your code when the page is going to pop from the navigation stack (i.e. when user goes back to the previous page whether using soft back button or physical back button).

Wrap your page inside a [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) widget, and put the code that you want to execute when the user is leaving the page in [onWillPop](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope/onWillPop.html) callback.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm trying to pass a function to the onWillPop with the following signature: `Future<bool> requestPop()` but I get following error: `the argument Future<bool> can't be assigned to the parameter type '() -> Future<bool>'`

Comment: I managed to solve it by myself, just wrote directly the code of the function directly in the widget property.